# Markdown table in discord

Tags: discord, markdown

I would like to post a `markdown` table in a simple `discord` message, but this doesn't work. Here is some markdown table I would like to test:

```
| Month    | Savings |
| -------- | ------- |
| January  | $250    |
| February | $80     |
| March    | $420    |
```

When posting in discord:

[image]

So as you can see it doesn't return in a markdown table. I was wondering if it is possible to post markdown tables in a discord message?

Comment: No, it's not possible.